# Usar el ORDER BY en un select con ROLLUP

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2005

Tengo un Stored procedure que me trae la siguiente información:

- Zona (se usa como agrupador en el rollup)
- Tienda
- Pedidos Recibidos
- Pedidos Aceptados
- Pedidos Negados
- Porcentaje de aceptación

[image: Resultado de la consulta con el rollup de zonas]

Esta información, mi usuario quiere consultarla en un aspx. Mi único problema, es que solicita que se ordene por **Total de pedidos *POR ZONA*** ordenando por zona JUNTO a sus respectivas tiendas lo mas parecido a la última imagen. (Ese se hizo con reporting services y el report builder por lo que fue mas fácil hacer el ordenamiento que requiero, pero el usuario lo quiere forzosamente en un aspx)

[image: Imagen con Order By]

[image: Ordenamiento requerido]

Anexo el query que estoy usando para la consulta

```
set dateformat dmy
select id_tienda,SUBSTRING (ZONA, 6,15) as ZONA, a.PREFERENCIA,nombre_boutique,COUNT(id_tienda) as total_pedidos,isnull(SUM(aceptado),0) as aceptados,isnull(SUM(negado),'0') as negados,  
case when sum(aceptado)>0   then convert(numeric,isnull(SUM(aceptado),0)*100/(isnull(sum(aceptado),0)+isnull(sum(negado),0)),2)     else '0'  end as Porcentaje_Aceptacion 
into #Surtimento
from vw_estatus p inner join ALMACEN a on p.id_tienda = a.ID_TIENDA_EXTERNO where 1=1  and fecha_peticion >= @FechaI
and fecha_peticion <= @FechaF and comentario<>'CANCELACION AUTOMATICA-NO SE CUENTA CON STOCK EN EL SISTEMA' 
group by ZONA,nombre_boutique,id_tienda, a.PREFERENCIA 
ORDER BY ZONA,a.PREFERENCIA asc, COUNT(id_Tienda) desc


SELECT ZONA as Zona, 
id_tienda + ' - ' + Nombre_Boutique as Tienda, 
--PREFERENCIA as [Nivel Top], 
isnull(sum(total_pedidos),0) as [Total de Pedidos],
isnull(sum(aceptados),0) as [Pedidos Aceptados],
isnull(sum(negados),0) as [Pedidos Negados],
sum(Porcentaje_Aceptacion) as [% de Aceptación] FROM #Surtimento WHERE Porcentaje_Aceptacion Between @PorcentajeI and @PorcentajeF
group by rollup(zona,id_tienda + ' - ' + Nombre_Boutique)
order by sum(total_pedidos) desc
```

Comment: Entonces el problema es que quieres ordenar según cierto criterio o quieres filtrar las filas con los detalles?

Comment: El problema es que por el momento necesito ordenar por la suma de total de pedidos por zona, ya que aún no me definen si va a haber criterios para ordenar las tiendas.

Comment: Pero en la imagen que pusiste está ordenando por total de pedidos por zona

Comment: pero las tiendas no se ordenan dentro de su respectiva zona, y lo que requiero es ordenar el agrupoado TOTAL (suma de zonas y las tiendas de la respectiva zona)

Comment: bueno, eso es diferente que decir que necesitas orden por la suma de total de pedidos por zona

Comment: OK... ¿se entiende mejor ahora con el edit? o ¿cuál seria la manera correcta de expresarlo para que quede claro fácilmente?

Comment: Ya se entiende más claro. Puse una respuesta para que pruebes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin tener acceso a tus datos es un poco difícil testear código. De todas formas, yo trataría de usar `SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY)`:

```
SELECT  Zona, 
        id_tienda + ' - ' + Nombre_Boutique as Tienda, 
        ISNULL(SUM(total_pedidos),0) as [Total de Pedidos],
        ISNULL(SUM(aceptados),0) as [Pedidos Aceptados],
        ISNULL(SUM(negados),0) as [Pedidos Negados],
        SUM(Porcentaje_Aceptacion) as [% de Aceptación] 
FROM (  SELECT *, SUM(total_pedidos) OVER(PARTITION BY Zona) Total_Zona
        FROM #Surtimento) T 
WHERE Porcentaje_Aceptacion BETWEEN @PorcentajeI AND @PorcentajeF
GROUP BY ROLLUP(zona, id_tienda + ' - ' + Nombre_Boutique)
ORDER BY MIN(Total_Zona) DESC, SUM(total_pedidos) DESC
;
```

Comment: Excelente, justo lo que necesitaba. Lo único es que me pone los totales antes de la región sureste pero eso se puede ocultar sin problemas. Muchas gracias.